# populate mat-select (ngModel) programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to populate a mat-select programmatically without using a formGroup.
I've only found solutuions with formGroups. But you cant use "ngForm" amd formGroup together.

```html
<form #filterForm="ngForm" appIdentityRevealed>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select name="selectReports" [(ngModel)]="reportIds" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let report of filterReport" [value]="report.databaseId">
        {{report.Name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="markAllReports()">
              Alle Berichte auswählen
            </button>
  <div class="space-top ">
    <button type="submit " color="primary " mat-raised-button (click)="submit ">---</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When i add Ids to the array reportIds the mat-select **does not update/refresh**.

My code to add ids:

```
markAllReports() {
  this.allReports.map(x => x.reportTyp ? this.reportIds.push(x.databaseId) : null)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
markAllReports() {
  tempArray:any=[];
  this.allReports.map(x => x.reportTyp ? tempArray.push(x.databaseId) :  null);
  this.reportIds=tempArray
 }
```

Comment: This is wrong. When i add Ids to my reportIds array without using the mat-select (through the markAllReports() button), the mat-select does not show theses added Ids as checked/marked

Comment: ohh .. okay...  push do not  trigger update . Replace your push with  temp array.. let's say you add all values to tempArray first and then assign reportIds= tempArray. Hope this should work for you.

Comment: I forgot that you need to do this in angular sometimes.... :D
Vaction was too long. Thx, now everything works fine!